# Calling google app script from js file

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to call the google script function from js file.The script contains only the function names from other scripts. When tried calling the script it shows Error "Function not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **google.script.run.functionName()**

reference here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run